# Locating original Stack Exchange chat room for GIS site?

Tags: discussion, chat, announcements

**WARNING**

The chat room linked to below the line below was frozen about six years ago.  The link is being left there for historical interest but please **do NOT seek to unfreeze and use it**.

Instead visit the [current GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).

---

I've created a room for our humble site, available at:
  http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142/gis

Comment: Unfortunately, need 20 rep in MSO to participate.  I don't qualify :)

Comment: I think if you hit up http://meta.stackoverflow.com and login, you should get 100 rep for linking your accounts together, at least that's how it worked for me...

Comment: Whoo hoo!  Unassociated then re-associated my other accounts on Meta, and got the 100 bonus for associating with a 200+ rep account.  Had to hit http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/logout to trigger an update.  Of course, when I got in, nobody else was there. :)

Comment: Bummer. It's frozen, a state from which there appears to be no return. Maybe the creator needs to poke at it or something to thaw it back out.

Comment: I can't seem to unfreeze it, unfortunately. It wasn't an active spot and I gather they're looking to prevent 'rot' as they previously had issues on SE 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The current GIS Chat Room is located at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis

Please use this to [ask questions about GIS tutorials, Training opportunities, Recent happenings](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3516/where-is-the-proper-place-to-ask-questions-about-gis-tutorials-training-opportun), and any other questions that are a poor fit for the focussed Q&A format of Main.