# Where is proper place to ask questions about GIS tutorials,Training opportunities, Recent happenings, etc?

Tags: discussion, scope, chat

I recently got a new job as a GIS Coordinator for a state government office and I want to email our GIS users occasionally with GIS related stuff like mentioned above. I wanted to post asking users if they knew of any good sources that post these kinds of things and I could incorperate them into my program but I wasnt sure what the proper area was to ask such a question.

Comment: We have an internal Wiki-pedia 'GIS Wiki' with all the related information. From scratch it takes time to pull all the information together but is worth the time as users add more it becomes more a 'one stop shop'

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647274/good-wiki-software-for-internal-company-use

Comment: Thanks this is something I will look into.

Comment: @Mapperz this has peaked my interest however I dont have much experience in web development or .php, Is there a Wiki site that caters to people like me, or do you kinda need to know that stuff to create a wiki.

Comment: Nor do we, we just installed it on a virtual web-server and it worked out of the box. If you have edited Wikipedia online it should be as easy as that.

Comment: @Mapperz sorry for all the questions/sidebar just one last thing. Did you use the MediaWiki they mention in the post you referenced or some other wiki software.

Comment: To meet my wiki requirements I use Atlassian Confluence which is very easy to administer.

Comment: yes MediaWiki is used there are others http://www.clickonf5.org/7599/10-free-opensource-wiki-software-engine/

Comment: If you want to use something dead simple, with a plaintext data store, try Dokuwiki; it's underappreciated in the above posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be asking whether the place for such questions on GIS Stack Exchange is Main or Meta or ...?

I think the place for open-ended, and more conversational, questions is the [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) which can be accessed from the GUI using instructions at [Where are GIS Chat Rooms?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/where-are-gis-chat-rooms)